# java.net.UnknownHostException while using p:captcha

Tags: jsf, primefaces, captcha

I am getting the below error while using [`<p:captcha>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/captcha.xhtml) component.

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api-verify.recaptcha.net
```

Steps Performed:

1. Registered for Captcha on www.google.com/recaptcha with localhost as well as system hostname.
2. Updated the public and private key in web.xml file.
3. Tried with PrimeFaces 3.4,5.1 jars.

I have read in certain forums that global keys should work with localhost. I don't see the option to generate global keys on Google reCaptcha site.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wrong hostname? No outgoing internet access from the server? Wrong dns server?